# Angular modal close and submit

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to get a modal to set up to have a close or submit after it is open.  It opens successfuly however I cannot implement a close or submit.  I'm not familiar at all with angular and I've been trying to figure this out for days.  Here is the controller for the modal open.

```
( function () {        
    function ModalCtrl ($uibModal) {            
        this.open = function() {
            console.log("Open sesame.")
            var mobalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl : '/templates/modals.html',
                controller: 'ModalCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'modal'
            });
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('blocChat')
        .controller('ModalCtrl', ['$uibModal', ModalCtrl]);
})();
```

and I have a controller for modal close and submit that are unsuccessful as of this moment.  Here's where I've left off.

```
( function () {
    function ModalCloseSubmitCtrl ($uibModal, ModalCtrl) {            
        var modal = ModalCtrl;

        this.submit = function() {
            console.log("submitted!")
            $uibModal.submit(modal);
            };


        this.close = function() {
            console.log("Closed successfully.")
            $uibModal.close({$value: modal});
            };
    }

    angular
        .module('blocChat')
        .controller('ModalCloseSubmitCtrl', ['$uibModal', 'ModalCtrl', ModalCloseSubmitCtrl]);
})();
```

I've tried reading the documentation, but it's just not clicking.  If someone could point out how to properly link the functionality together I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks for your time.

Here are the html templates, one for each controller.

```
<div ng-repeat="room in roomController.rooms">{{ room.$value }}</div>

<button type="button"
        ng-click="mod.open()">Create new room</button>


</div>
```

This is the template that where the close and submit modal functions come into play.

```
<div>
<input type="submit"
    ng-controller="ModalCloseSubmitCtrl as mods"
    ng-submit= "mods.submit()">Submit room name.
<button type="button"
    ng-controller="ModalCloseSubmitCtrl as mods"
    ng-click= "mods.close()">Close</button>
```

Comment: Can you share the template (*modals.html*)?

Comment: Just did thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

The $uibModal in the closeController is different from the instance that you opened in the ModalCtrl, so I suggest to append the close event to the modalInstance in the first ModalCtrl and keep all the logic in a single service

Comment: I would like to do so but this is an assignment and my teacher told me to do it this way.  Quite a few examples I've looked at did it in the way you suggested but my hands are tied on this one.